# How can I reprogram a USB to appear as a CD or HD?

Tags: firmware

I know this is possible either by modifying the firmware or doing something with the partition, but does anybody know how? This can be done? Specifically I am wanting the USB drive to read as a HD or CD when plugged into the computer.

Edit:

I want to be able to convert other USB drives, doing it for other people, etc. I know they can be bought but I want to learn to do it on my own.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably much better ways of doing it but if you look around (eBay) you can still get flash drives with the [U3 firmware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U3) that allows flash drives to emulate CD ROM drives. The U3 *software* to set the drive up only works on Windows, but once it's set up it will emulate a CD drive transparently regardless of OS.